# how to use np.random.rand to create an array where r is between -100 and 100 when calling from a seed

Tags: python, numpy

Here is what I have so far

```
    import numpy as np
    np.random.seed(1)
    p12=np.random.rand(3,5)*100 -100 
    print ("p12a = ")
    print (p12)
```

and this is the output

```
    p12a = 
    [[ -1.1139 -25.1834 -71.9556 -21.0721 -89.6774]
    [-55.2106  -9.1404 -70.6386 -71.2225 -86.9971]
    [-98.0633 -32.1164 -78.8372 -73.4453 -50.8427]]
```

how do I get the outputs to not all be negative but still have r be between -100 and 100?

Comment: Have you tried using different values for scaling the output of `rand`? Hint: it generates values between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.random.uniform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html#numpy.random.uniform).

```
np.random.uniform(-100, 100, (3, 5))
```

This will generate a (3x5) NumPy array with floats between -100 (inclusive) and +100 (**exclusive**).

Note that the upper bound is exclusive! This may or may not be suitable for your use case.